# CSS 3d transform animates under other elements in webkit only

Tags: html, css, webkit, transform

I have a fairly simple 3d transform which is essentially a bunch of flip cards which can be flipped front to back and vice versa. When they are flipped I want the animation to overlap the other cards. This works perfectly in Firefox however the animation occurs underneath the other cards in Webkit.

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ojdavey/kwf8vLLx/1/

If you click the "Flip" button in both Chrome/Safari and Firefox you'll see how it works differently.

I've tried a couple of things such as setting:

```
transform-style: flat
```

for the other cards while the card is flipping but that didn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to set the `z-index` on the parent container, when a card is flipped, like:

```
.box.flip.active {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Remove this class from all elements and add it to the current card before you flip it either way. This works in Safari as well as in Chrome.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/388zbz3s/)

The demo includes the updated JavaScript code too. *This is not optimized. It's only to demonstrate the behavior:*

```
$(".flip .flip-button").on("click", function() {
    $('.col4').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".col4").addClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".card").addClass("flipped");
});

$(".flip .close").on("click", function() {
    $('.col4').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".col4").addClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".card").removeClass("flipped");
});
```